# исключить ноль в парсинге регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

имеется текст

```
"text":"0.116934200"
"text":"0.0099"
"text":"0"
"text":"4"
"text":"90"
```

чтоб регулярка парсила   все кроме "text":"0"
подскажите пожалуйста поиском не нашел нечего подобного

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вполне уверен, на каком языке должно быть написано и какой должен быть результат, но, возможно, этот вариант на JavaScript подойдёт:

```js
const string = '"text":"0.116934200" "text":"0.0099" "text":"0" "text":"4" "text":"90"';

const regexp = /"text":(?!"0")"[\d.]+"/g;

console.log(string.match(regexp));
```

Comment: Я думаю, автор хотел получить значение после `text`, но кроме нуля. Регулярка хорошая, но ответа на это не дает.  Чуть поменял, первая группа`"text":(?!"0")"([^"]+)"`

Comment: Да, если автору нужны только числа и не нужна проверка того, что во вторых кавычках, тогда так)

Comment: спасибо это то что надо